# How to fix loadURL webView in android studio?

Tags: android, webview

hello everyone i have problem to view this url :" https://socindonesia.com " in my webview, can someone help me please.

this is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);


        webView.loadUrl("https://socindonesia.com");


    }
}
```

Comment: what problems do you have?

Comment: Please describe your issue clearly

Comment: @DemiDust i cannot load my url in simulator, i have used internet pemission in androidManifest.xml

Comment: @ivkil the problem is i cannot be load my url : socindonesia.com, i think my code clearly but still cannot be load, do u have idea? thanks so much

Comment: activity_main.xml contains the webView?

Comment: post your code for activity_main.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your website requires Web Storage API to run properly, you need to enable it in WebView settings - `webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true)`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the internet permission in your manifest file. I think the rest of the code looks good. we also have to make one change to AndroidManifest.xml, adding a line
where we request permission to access the Internet:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

If we fail to add this permission, the browser will refuse to load pages.

Comment: i have used <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> in AndroidManifest.xml but still cannot be load

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>